# Highlight matching parenthesis, only in Lisp mode (and maybe a few similar modes)

Tags: minor-mode, highlighting, buffer-local, emacs-lisp-mode, delimiters

is there a way to have the **global minor mode** `show-paren-mode`
functionality as a buffer-local minor mode? I love its behavior but only for Lisp.

Searching for a package I can see a number of close tries but no bullseye.
I do not want the "electric" behavior of automatically inserting the
matching delimiter; I just want to be visually reminded of the mate of
the delimiter under point.  The closest seems to be the GNU package
`flylisp`, but it's from .. 2014 ?

Comment: isn't enough to add it to the hook of the modes you want it enabled?

Comment: @Muihlinn No, it is a **global** minor mode. Enabling it in any hook switches it on for all buffers.

Comment: @Tobias True, I've rephrased the question to highlight it and posted an anwer from Malabarba's site from a while ago.

Comment: You can make it behaving as buffer-local. Arthur Malabarba [posted how](https://endlessparentheses.com/locally-configure-or-disable-show-paren-mode.html) a while ago.